# Does Mvvmcross has support for IOS BottomSheetController

Tags: ios, mvvmcross, bottom-sheet

Mvvmcross has perfect support for BottomSheetDialogFragment, Android. It is possible to specify view model and display bottom sheet by navigating to it.

I didn't find something similar for ios.
Does MVVMCross supports BottomSheetController?
Links to Github repos or blogs are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with custom presentation attribute and following code in ios presenter, which works fine with navigation service.

```
    public override void RegisterAttributeTypes()
    {
        base.RegisterAttributeTypes();

        AttributeTypesToActionsDictionary.Register<BottomSheetPresentationAttribute>(
            ShowBottomSheet,
            (viewModel, attribute) =>
            {
                if (_bottomSheetControllers.ContainsKey(viewModel))
                {
                    var bottomSheet = _bottomSheetControllers[viewModel];
                    _bottomSheetControllers.Remove(bottomSheet);

                    bottomSheet.DismissViewController(true, null);
                }
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            });
    }

    private Task<bool> ShowBottomSheet(Type viewType, BottomSheetPresentationAttribute attribute, MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        var contentController = BottomSheetsHelper.GetContentController(viewType);
        contentController.OnViewCreate(() => (request as MvxViewModelInstanceRequest).ViewModelInstance);

        var bottomSheet = new BottomSheetController(contentController);
        _bottomSheetControllers.Add(contentController.ViewModel, bottomSheet);

        Window.RootViewController.PresentViewController(bottomSheet, true, null);
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<object, BottomSheetController> _bottomSheetControllers = new Dictionary<object, BottomSheetController>();
```

Comment: Hello ! Im interested in your coude, do you have any sample ? I would like to see BottomSheetsHelper

Comment: All code present in answer, the only missing part is attribute itself. Just create new attribute class "BottomSheetPresentationAttribute", then add code from answer into ios presenter. Then use attribute on view models, which you want to present in bottom sheet.